# How to calculate the length of cable on a winch given the rotations of the drum

Tags: algorithm, function, geometry

I have a cable winch system that I would like to know how much cable is left given the number of rotations that have occurred and vice versa. This system will run on a low-cost microcontroller with low computational resources and should be able to update quickly, long for/while loop iterations are not ideal.

The inputs are cable diameter, inner drum diameter, inner drum width, and drum rotations. The output should be the length of the cable on the drum.

At first, I was calculating the maximum number of wraps of cable per layer based on cable diameter and inner drum width, I could then use this to calculate the length of cable per layer. The issue comes when I calculate the total length as I have to loop through each layer, a costly operation (could be 100's of layers).

My next approach was to precalculate a table with each layer, then perform a 3-5 degree polynomial regression down to an easy to calculate formula.

This appears to work for the most part, however, there are slight inaccuracies at the low and high end (0 rotations could be + or - a few units of cable length). The real issue comes when I try and reverse the function to get the current rotations of the drum given the length. So far, my reversed formula does not seem to equal the forward formula (I am reversing X and Y before calculating the polynomial).

I have looked high and low and cannot seem to find any formulas for cable length to rotations that do not use recursion or loops. I can't figure out how to reverse my polynomial function to get the reverse value without losing precision. If anyone happens to have an insight/ideas or can help guide me in the right direction that would be most helpful. Please see my attempts below.

```
// Units are not important

CableLength = 15000
CableDiameter = 5
DrumWidth = 50
DrumDiameter = 5

CurrentRotations = 0
CurrentLength = 0
CurrentLayer = 0

PolyRotations = Array
PolyLengths = Array
PolyLayers = Array

WrapsPerLayer = DrumWidth / CableDiameter

While CurrentLength < CableLength // Calcuate layer length for each layer up to cable length
  CableStackHeight = CableDiameter * CurrentLayer
  DrumDiameterAtLayer = DrumDiameter + (CableStackHeight * 2) // Assumes cables stack vertically
  WrapDiameter = DrumDiameterAtLayer + CableDiameter // Center point of cable
  WrapLength = WrapDiameter * PI
  LayerLength = WrapLength * WrapsPerLayer
  
  CurrentRotations += WrapsPerLayer // 1 Rotation per wrap
  CurrentLength += LayerLength
  CurrentLayer++
  
  PolyRotations.Push(CurrentRotations)
  PolyLengths.Push(CurrentLength)
  PolyLayers.Push(CurrentLayer)

End


// Using 5 degree polynomials, any lower = very low precision

PolyLengthToRotation = CreatePolynomial(PolyLengths, PolyRotations, 5) // 5 Degrees
PolyRotationToLength = CreatePolynomial(PolyRotations, PolyLengths, 5) // 5 Degrees

// 40 Rotations should equal about 3141.593 units
RealRotation = 40
RealLength = 3141.593
CalculatedLength = EvaluatePolynomial(RealRotation,PolyRotationToLength)
CalculatedRotations = EvaluatePolynomial(RealLength,PolyLengthToRotation)

// CalculatedLength = 3141.593 // Good
// CalculatedRotations = 41.069 // No good
// CalculatedRotations != RealRotation // These should equal


// 0 Rotations should equal 0 length
RealRotation = 0
RealLength = 0
CalculatedLength = EvaluatePolynomial(RealRotation,PolyRotationToLength)
CalculatedRotations = EvaluatePolynomial(RealLength,PolyLengthToRotation)

// CalculatedLength = 1.172421e-9 // Very close
// CalculatedRotations = 1.947, // No good
// CalculatedRotations != RealRotation // These should equal
```

Side note: I have a "spool factor" parameter to calibrate for the actual cable spooling efficiency that is not shown here. (cable is not guaranteed to lay mathematically perfect)

Comment: It's a sum of an arithmetic progression. Note that each layer is 2 * pi * t longer than the previous where t is the thickness of the table. In other words it's a closed form solution.

Comment: Gauss solved this in primary school for you ;)

Comment: As I understand, this would still require looping over each layer, using costly resources to calculate the length (calculation time is directly related to rotations). Is there a better way to process this equation at less than O(n)?

Comment: There is a closed formula for calculating the sum of an arithmetic series.

Comment: Already told you, although I meant "cable" not "table": it's O(1).

Comment: Why not use the volume-based approximation? All layers of cable on the winch can be approximated as a tube: the length of the tube is the width of the winch, the inner diameter of the tube is the winch diameter, the outer diameter is yet unknown. Writing a formula to calculate the volume of X meters of cable is trivial (approximate the cable with a hexagon for optimal packing). Then you can calculate the outer diameter of the tube of equal volume, and translate the outer diameter to the number of winds.

Answer (score 0):

@Bathsheba May have meant cable, but a table is a valid option (also experimental numbers are probably more interesting in the real world).

A bit slow, but you could always do it manually. There's only 40 rotations (though optionally for better experimental results, repeat 3 times and take the average...). Reel it completely in. Then do a rotation (depending on the diameter of your drum, half rotation). Measure and mark how far it spooled out (tape), record it. Repeat for the next 39 rotations. You now have a lookup table you can find the length in O(log N) via binary search (by sorting the data) and a bit of interpolation (IE: 1.5 rotations is about half way between 1 and 2 rotations).

You can also use this to derived your own experimental data. Do the same thing, but with a cable half as thin (perhaps proportional to the ratio of the inner diameter and the cable radius?). What effect does it have on the numbers? How about twice or half the diameter? Math says circumference is linear (2πr), so half the radius, half the amount per rotation. Might be easier to adjust the table data.

The gist is that it may be easier for you to have a real world reference for your numbers rather than relying purely on an abstract mathematically model (not to say the model would be wrong, but cables don't exactly always wind up perfectly, who knows perhaps you can find a quirk about your winch that would have lead to errors in a pure mathematical approach). Who knows might be able to derive the formula yourself :) with a fudge factor for the real world even lol.